# Rest call post method in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I am writing restcalls for get and post methods.Here is the code.

```
public class RestCall
    {
        public static string loginJsonString;
        public static string xmlResult;

        // GET: RestCall
        public async Task RunAsync(string name, string value)
        {
            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
                var urlRestGet = HomeController.url;
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlRestGet + "?name=" + name + "&value=" + value + "");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(urlRestGet + "?name=" + name + "&value=" + value + "");

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Get the response
                    loginJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    //Converting to xml
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(loginJsonString)))
                    {
                        var output = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
                        xmlResult=XDocument.Load(JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(stream, output)).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Post
        public async Task RunAsync()
        {
            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response;
                    Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
                    vehicle.Model = "Vehicle1";
                    vehicle.Description = "Description1ForVehicle1";
                    vehicle.ETag = "";
                    response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("xxx",vehicle);
                    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
                        Uri vehicleUri = response.Headers.Location;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

My get method works fine. But post method throws an exception "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

1)If it is an newtonsoft error why does my get method works?

2)How can I resolve this?

My web.config file shows,

```
    <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" 
             publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Have you added reference for Newtonsoft.Json? If yes, which version, you have added..

Comment: @RMD Update your NewtonSoft.Json nuget package to latest version 11 and this issue should get resolved

Comment: The 'Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is 
'2.8.50926.663'.- gives this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you don't have Newtonsoft.Json assembly referenced in your project.

This can be caused:

1. If you (force) removed Newtonsoft.Json Nuget package from your project.
2. If you have wrong binding redirects (check your *web.config*)
3. Wrong assembly gets loaded into */bin* which can be caused by wrong *HintPath* attribute

Last thing, your *Read* method works because you don't use Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize response you get. However, *Post* method causes an exception since you are using `PostAsJsonAsync` method which underneath relies upon Newtonsoft.Json library.

Comment: I have added about the version in web.config to the question.

Comment: @RMD I presume you have Newtonsoft.Json assembly added as a reference to the project which hosts application. It seems to me, that the path from which CLR tries to load dll is wrong. Could you verify that by searching through loaded assemblies (Debug->Windows->Modules window in VS)